# Reimbursement for business use of personal phone

Tags: united-states, california

I work at a small company located in California. The company has indicated that they would like to begin forwarding all calls outside of business hours to my phone.

In actuality there would be very few calls going to my phone. I understand that in California, the company is required to either provide me with a company-issued phone for business purposes or provide me with some type of reimbursement. My question is whether the reimbursement is based on usage? In other words, can the company tell me that they are not obligated to reimburse me if very few or no calls end up going to my phone?

Comment: https://www.natlawreview.com/article/hold-phone-reimbursing-employees-cell-phone-use-california suggests that there are no clear rules.  The law specifies a "reasonable percentage" but gives no guidance as to what is "reasonable".

Comment: Your company tries to oblige you to carry your personal phone with you. People might not want to do it. Or say I forget my phone at home, my boss has no right to complain about it.